# Python console printing name of getLoggers

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm having a persistent and painfull issue with my VSC python terminal. I needed to add a personal library to the path of a script, and I don't know what did I do or change, but everytime I run the script it prints something called "name of getLogger" and I don't know how to erase that.

For example, if I want to import datetime library, the terminal seems fine:

```
from datetime import date 
from sys import path as sys_path
```

[normal imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q433E.png)

But as soon as I add another my propietary path, it starts printing "name of getLogger":

```
from datetime import date 
from sys import path as sys_path

if r"C:\apps\Mart" not in sys_path:
    sys_path.insert(1, r"C:\apps\Mart")

from mart.market_data.exch_rates import ExchangeRates
```

[import of library with "name of getLogger" prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dybv.png)

This is a very annoying print... does anyone know what did I do to have this mess of printings and how to solve it please?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do yu have this problem when you run directly in normal console? Maybe it is displayed by some functions in VSC console or in IPython. Some tools to develop code may try to make life easier and they display some information even if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to introduce logger first. Many programs have the need to record logs, and the information contained in the logs includes not only normal program access logs, but also errors, warnings and other information output. Python's logging module provides a standard log interface. You can store logs in various formats through it, which is mainly used to output operation logs. You can set the level of output logs, log saving path, log file rollback and so on. I think since normal import will not cause problems,that should be the content you imported below. It may import logging to view the log. However, it is generally applicable to simple programs. I think you can find the reason from the imported file